# Navigate Through List Of Divs On Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text input. I want it this way - When the user presses the down arrow key, the focus should shift from the input to the first element in the list of divs below the input and keep moving downwards as we keep pressing the down key, and when the user presses the enter key the text in that div should be set as the input value. And vice versa for the up arrow key, i.e. if the user presses the up arrow key, the focus should shift to the last element in the list and keep moving upwards as we keep pressing the up key.

Here is the fiddle I created - [Example](http://bit.ly/1lKXhZJ)

Comment: Please don't bypass the jsfiddle validation... post your code in the question

Comment: You can Use autocomplete widget . Here The documentation  http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: why don't you consider drop down <select><option> since this is more similar to your case?. Or else i misunderstand your requirement?

Comment: No @ManirajSS I want it exactly how I've asked

Comment: @KaranPatyal Can you please code a working example with the autocomplete widget you just suggested. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Here You can find Example http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, and make changes according to your requirement by going documentation.

Comment: @KaranPatyal Actually I already have a filter function which filters the divs according to the text inside the divs. So I can't use the autocomplete widget as it stores the data in an array. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var $list = $('#list').children();
    var index = 0;

    function down(){
        if(index == $list.length - 1) index = 0;
        else index++;           
        move();
    };
    function up(){
        if(index == 0) index = $list.length - 1;
        else index--;           
        move();
    };

    function enter(){
        var val = $($list[index]).html();
        $('input').val(val);
    };

    function move()
    {
        $list.removeClass('highlight');
        $($list[index]).addClass('highlight');
    };

    // highlights first element 
    move();

    $('input').on('keydown', function(e){
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case 13:
                enter();
                break;
            case 40:
                down();
                break;
            case 38:
                up();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tt0nnzvm/4/

EDIT: Updated the fiddle and code

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I wanted, but there is one problem. I saw that you added the 'highlight' class manually to the first element. Actually, my tool works in a different way. As soon as the user types, I have a function that filters the div based on text according to the value in the input. So, is there any way I can select the first element in the filtered list? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I can't seem to integrate your code with my tool, so I need your help again :( I've created a fiddle which replicates my tool. It searches according to the text in the divs and filters them accordingly. So please help me out. Sorry for the trouble. Here it is - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yashghelani/tt0nnzvm/6/)

Comment: Sorry I'm not at a PC no more, on my phone. I can have a look later on tonight when I get home.

Comment: Okay sure! But don't forget to update it with your solution. I really need it to work.

Comment: Hey, you didn't help me out. Are you busy?

Comment: Sorry, I was out yesterday. Which part are you not able to get to work?

**EDIT:** Is it because the list is dynamically being filtered? What you will need to do is instead of hiding and showing. Create a new list to render on which you apply the key up/down arrow logic on. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have created a fiddle which replicates the code in my tool. There is a function which filters the div according to the text in it. So I tried but I couldn't integrate your code with my code. Can you please help me out. Here is the fiddle - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yashghelani/tt0nnzvm/6/)

Comment: I looked at the fiddle, heres the steps needed to integrate the code: Create a new list based on filtered results, Render the newly created list, Apply key up/down logic to that new list

Sorry i don't have the time right now to code it right now as I'm out and about. I can have a look at it further when I get the chance!

Comment: Hey I tried but still couldn't do it. Can you help me. Here is the fiddle - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yashghelani/b5hawacp/1/)

Comment: Hi, please find the updated fiddle with the working code. Please note that this is quite messy and i would HIGHLY recommend reworking this. http://jsfiddle.net/b5hawacp/7/. Also please accept my answer as it answered your original question. Thanks :)